# RTextTools - Multiple Classifiers

Tags: r, classification

I am stuck (again) and in need of wisdom.  This time I'm trying to classify a pile of documents where each doc could have 1:n classifications.

The RTextTools example dataset NYTIMES assigns a single topic code to each story and therefore the worked examples just... work.

BUT in reality many news stories can have multiple codes. So what if rather than having NYTimes$Topic.Code you had a structure more like...

```
Article_ID Date     Title       Subject          Topic.Code
1          1-Jan-96 A Title     A subject text   2
2          1-Jan-96 B Title     B subject text   1,2
3          2-Jan-96 C Title     C subject text   3
4          3-Jan-96 D Title     D subject text   2,3
and so on...
```

This could also be represented with the Topic.Code separated out in to separate columns for each unique code and set TRUE/FALSE...

```
Article_ID Date     Title       Subject          Topic.Code1 Topic.Code2 Topic.Code3
1          1-Jan-96 A Title     A subject text   FALSE       TRUE        FALSE
2          1-Jan-96 B Title     B subject text   TRUE        TRUE        FALSE
3          2-Jan-96 C Title     C subject text   FALSE       FALSE       TRUE
4          3-Jan-96 D Title     D subject text   FALSE       TRUE        TRUE
and so on...
```

How on earth would you go about trying to train against this 1:n situation using RTextTools?

Comment: I don't know RTextTools and I'm not sure I understand what you need to do. But if it's going from the first format you describe (where Topic.Code = 2; 1,2; etc.) to the second, there are ways to do that using basic R functions. But is that what you need or is it rather specific to the functionning of RTextTools?

Comment: Chaps sorry perhaps I am not putting this right at all then.  I can have the data in either format readily enough BUT what I am trying to work out is how, using RTextTools to do classification where more than one class might be valid.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for clarifying. Unfortunately since I don't know RTextTools I can only wish you luck!

Comment: I'm very interested in a solution, but lack experience with RTextTools.  Could you run multiple single-topic analysis and then cbind the results?  Thus, each Subject element would be classified as T or F for the presence of each topic?

Comment: lawyeR - this seems like a potential approach BUT I have 126 topics (labels) and 850k docs for the training set (only 3500 for the test set thankfully).     My understanding is sufficiently poor to grasp but I think that would entail training 125 binary classifiers which i) would require a lot of code and ii) take an eternity to run.    I was kinda hoping there might be a "simple" approach baked in to RTextTools

Answer (score 0):

RTextTools is not meant for Multi-dependent variable classifications. You could use a multi-perceptron network. If you still wanted to use RTextTools, use the values of the topics as factors so that each combination of topics is identified as a single factor.